# Manage service account password policy

Tags: windows, active-directory, security

I recently inherited a system with over 40 VMs, each may contains applications such as web server, database server, 3rd party application ect...

The authentication for these use domain authentication via the Active Directory server;  It currently does not have the password policy such as expiration period, password complexity ect..

I want to change this, but managing service account password update every 6 months on 40+ VMs with multiple applications is truly daunting task along with risks such as server downtime, human error ect..

If this is SQL server or standard application then I could have written some Powershell script to automate it but in my case there are many different custom applications.

I want you to ask of your experience, do you ever have to do this and if so how do you go about it? Are there tools or best practice standard out there on how to manage periodic service account password change?

Comment: It's really not clear why you would need to update every VM individually.

Comment: I guess you can give me advice then.  The VMs I inherit currently have the password set in multiple ways such as in their window service, in certain configuration file, in certain task scheduler, in SQL job settings ect... pretty much anywhere that allow the user to put in a domain service account and password.  Each VM could be different form others, they aren't necessary the same.

Comment: If possible, use a Group Managed Service Account. GMSA's manage their own password. I've also seen scheduled tasks and services that use an AD or local account and it's completely unnecessary. They could have been configured to use LocalService/LocalSystem.